# @Ajax.ActionLink not sent data to controller ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using `ASP.Net MVC 5` and `Razor Engine`.
I want to implement a page to show products using ajax .

This is my code :

HomeController :

```
public ActionResult GoodDetails(int id)
    {
        Models.NishtmanDBEntities db = new NishtmanDBEntities();
        BlGoodDetail blGoodDetail = new BlGoodDetail();
        HomeVM vm = new HomeVM();

        var goodDetails = db.GoodDetails.Where(p => p.FKSubGoods == id).ToList();
        vm.GoodDetails = goodDetails;
        return View(vm);

    }
public PartialViewResult GoodDetailsAjax(int id)
    {
        HomeVM vm = new HomeVM();
        var GoodDetailsAjax = db.GoodDetails.Where(p => p.DetailsGoodID == id).ToList();
        vm.GoodDetails = GoodDetailsAjax;
        return PartialView("_GoodDetailsAjax", vm);
    }
```

**GoodDetails.cshtml:**

```
@model NP1.ViewModels.HomeVM
@section scripts{
  <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
  }

<div style="width: 100%; background-color: white;">
    @foreach (var item1 in Model.GoodDetails)
       {
     <a href="@Url.Action("GoodDetailsAjax", "Home", new { id = @item1.DetailsGoodID })">
     @Ajax.ActionLink(" ", "GoodDetailsAjax", new AjaxOptions()
          {
              HttpMethod = "GET",
              UpdateTargetId = "DivAjax",
              InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
          }
          )


    <input type="image" class="img-responsive" style="width:120px; height:120px;" src="@Url.Content(item1.DetailsSmallImage1.ToString())">

</a>
 }
 </div>
 <div id="DivAjax">

</div>
```

**_GoodDetailsAjax.cshtml:**

```
@model NP1.ViewModels.HomeVM
<div>
 @foreach (var item in Model.GoodDetails)
 {
    <img class="img-responsive" src="@Url.Content(item.DetailsImage1.ToString())" style="width:400px;height:320px;">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="@Url.Content(item.DetailsImage2.ToString())" style="width:400px;height:320px;">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="@Url.Content(item.DetailsImage3.ToString())" style="width:400px;height:320px;">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="@Url.Content(item.DetailsImage3.ToString())" style="width:400px;height:320px;">

}
```

my quetion is :There are no error, why it didn't work ? when I click on images in `GoodDetails` nothing happened .

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: There are no error , codes not working . images didn't show in partial view

Comment: did you check Model.GoodDetails count

Comment: Yeah , It's true , I think my code is not correct . when I click on Images didn't get any new url and shows same image in new window :/

Comment: hmm i think that is the problem.

Comment: Please check GoodDetailsAjax.Count in your controller.

Comment: Yep , I think , the id of images didn't send to `partial view` and I don't know how do it :/

Comment: Sorry , I don't know what do you mean . In my table in database there are a lots of entity .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98201/discussion-between-parth-trivedi-and-shima-amini).

Comment: You can use `OnSuccess` for getting the error message.

Comment: `OnSuccess`? ,Sorry , I don't know anything about it . Could you explain a little more  please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(" ", "GoodDetailsAjax", new { id = @item1.DetailsGoodID }, new AjaxOptions()
{
HttpMethod = "GET",
UpdateTargetId = "DivAjax",
InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
}
)
```

you are not passing `new { id = @item1.DetailsGoodID }` to ActionLink. that is the problem you are not getting `id` in Controller Action.

Comment: sorry for a lots of your time , I try this but it didn't work yet . now everything is ok but ... , Thank you again